# Nested Service promise not resolved in then()

Tags: angularjs

I got a service which first need to retrieve an accesstoken and then a User object. When this is done, further UI actions needs to be taken. The problem I have is that login().then() is invoked with a valid Session.accesstoken but a non-resolved promise for the Session.user. So I can't do any logic based on the user's info (e.g. role, etc.)

The following code I have:

In controllers.js (login() is invoked upon form credentials button click)

```
.controller('LoginController', 
function($scope, SessionService) {
    $scope.credentials = {
      username : '',
      password : ''
    };

    $scope.login =
      function() {
        SessionService.login($scope.credentials).then(function() {
          console.info("succesfully logged in as user " + JSON.stringify(Session)); 
          // further UI actions..
        });
      };
   })
```

In services.js

```
.factory('SessionService',
  function(User, Session, AuthorizationService) {
    return {
      login : function(credentials) {
        return AuthorizationService.requestToken(credentials)
          .then(function(token) {
            console.info("Got token: " + token);
            if (!!token) {
              Session.create(token);

              console.info("Fetching user...");
              return User.get({
                id : 'me'
              });
            } else {
              throw (new Error("Could not log in"));
            }
          }).then(function(user) {
            console.info("Got user: " + user);
            if (!!user) {
              Session.user = user;
            } else {
              throw (new Error("Could not fetch user"));
            }
          });
      },
    };
  })
```

Here is the output of the console:

- Got token: cf9c0eba82d872508f7dcc0b234f0d52 services.js:120
- Fetching user...
- services.js:124 Got user: [object Object]
- services.js:132 succesfully logged in as user
  {"token":"cf9c0eba82d772508f7dcc0b234f0d52","user":{"$promise":{},"$resolved":false}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` object is created by `$resource` and is not a promise; it is the actual object that will eventually be populated with the user info, but at this point of the code it contains nothing.

The solution is simple: from the first `then` do:

```
return User.get({...}).$promise;
```

The next `then` will be invoked with the user object as expected, but only when the data is actually fetched.